# what is the difference between bulk insert and array insert in Mongo db operations

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am wondering how following queries varies in performance.
I understand that bulk insert executes in sequence and normal/array inserts also executes in sequence.

**BULK INSERT**

```
var bulk = db.items.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.insert( { _id: 1, item: "abc123", status: "A", soldQty: 5000 } );
bulk.insert( { _id: 2, item: "abc456", status: "A", soldQty: 150 } );
bulk.insert( { _id: 3, item: "abc789", status: "P", soldQty: 0 } );
bulk.execute( { w: "majority", wtimeout: 5000 } );
```

**Normal INSERT**

```
db.items.insert( { _id: 1, item: "abc123", status: "A", soldQty: 5000 } );
db.items.insert( { _id: 2, item: "abc456", status: "A", soldQty: 150 } );
db.items.insert( { _id: 3, item: "abc789", status: "P", soldQty: 0 } );
```

**Array INSERT**

```
var array_insert = [
{ _id: 1, item: "abc123", status: "A", soldQty: 5000 } ,
{ _id: 2, item: "abc456", status: "A", soldQty: 150 } ,
{ _id: 3, item: "abc789", status: "P", soldQty: 0 } 
] ;
db.items.insert( array_insert );
```

Can any one explain what is the difference interms of performance or benefits for the above queries ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bulk insert is faster because inserts are sent all at once. Compare it to the regular flow where you send one insert, wait for server reply and only then send next insert.

It takes server the same amount of work to insert all the things, regardless of the mode (bulk vs. regular). In regular mode time is lost on client while it waits for server to respond. Not necessarily because server is slow. Network may be slow too.

Batching requests is a common way of speeding up application, regardless of the database used. See, for example, [pipelining in Redis](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining).

Comment: Thanks. Thats fine. But what about, if store all collections in to array and insert as single item ? will that be equal to bulk operation ?

Comment: "will that be equal" - speed-wise it'll be similar. Funtionality-wise - not even close (you now have another data structure)

Comment: What functionality will be different in Array insert ?

Comment: Functionality of your app. Due to the different data structure, some queries  will be faster, some will be slower and some - impossible.

Comment: Thanks. In this scenario, do you see any functionality difference between bulk and array ?

Comment: It also depends on what exactly you mean by "array insert". db.collection.insert command in mongodb shell, when passed an array, it will insert separate documents. This is kind of a bulk insert. But you won't work in the shell. So it falls on the driver for your programming language to do the right thing. Some may be smarter and do the bulk operation. Some may be dumber and do one-by-one inserts.

Comment: FYI, the `mongo` shell (2.6 or newer) definitely does convert `db.collection.insert([..])` into a bulk insert using the new API if the server supports it (ref: [mongo/shell/collection.js](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.6/src/mongo/shell/collection.js#L235)). This may also be the case for 2.2+ and the older bulk insert API (see [SERVER-2395](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2395)), but that's rather moot since those versions are no longer maintained. More importantly, real applications will use programming language drivers rather than the shell ;-).